# How to update Git Bash?

Tags: bash, git-bash

I want to update bash to the latest version. How to do that? I am on  a Windows 10.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
```

I tried:

```
bash --Update
```

didt work

```
bash --self-update
```

didnt work

Comment: Maybe `bash --do-what-i-want-and-do-it-now`

Comment: @ceving    bash: --do-what-i-want-and-do-: **invalid option**, didnt work, I tried that

Comment: I know. It was a joke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash does not have the ability to update itself!

Software updates on a computer are limited to a super user. But Bash can be used by everybody. It does not make much sens to put the update functionality into a program, everybody can use, although only super users are allowed to do the update. This is the status quo on Unix, where Bash came from. On Windows, which came from DOS, a single user OS, the situation may be different.

Inventing non existing and not documented command line options is unrewarding.  Read [Bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html) to know, which command line options are available.

It is the work of a package manager to install software and to update software. Almost every operating system has its own package manager. Even on Windows there are at least two different package managers.

- If you use MSYS2, then you can update with [`pacman`](https://www.msys2.org/).
- If you use Cygwin, then you can use its [`setup`](https://cygwin.com/install.html).

BTW: The question is off-topic here. Try it at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Git bash updates are not managed on windows. You are supposed to download and reinstall on each version.

see https://superuser.com/questions/1260587/how-to-disable-git-bash-daily-updates-checking
You can have a "update check " option, but no real update.